# How Download Full size image from Google using c#

Tags: c#, image

Please help to find and download How Download Full size image from Google search using c#

Comment: You mean from the search? Or a printscreen of the google engine?

Comment: We are happy to help users, but we aren't here to do the work for you. Can you please provide us with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've already tried, and what specifically you need help with?

Comment: Why this question had 1 positive ? it dosen't accomplish the norms (neither)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void SaveImage(string filename, ImageFormat format) {

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl);
    Bitmap bitmap;  bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

    if (bitmap != null) 
      bitmap.Save(filename, format);

    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
    client.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You forgot `bitmap.Dispose()`... it's also a disposable. Though you should just be putting them in `using` blocks instead.